# Security exception: Permission Denial while trying to open Facebook app through appium inspector

Tags: android, appium, android-permissions, permission-denied

I am trying to start automation of facebook App. I logged out from the app and used   `dumpsys window windows | grep -E mCurrentFocus|mFocusedApp` to get the app activity and package. I got the values as `com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.account.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity`

I provide the values in the appium inspector to get locator values

```
{
  "deviceName": "xxxx",
  "udid": "xxxx",
  "appPackage": "com.facebook.katana",
  "platformName": "android",
  "appActivity": "com.facebook.account.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity"
}
```

but I am getting the error

```
exited with code 4294967295'; Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.account.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity } from null (pid=20151, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10206
```

I followed https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/writing-running-appium/android/activity-startup.md to check my activity ,

```
C:\Users\aswathy_krishnan>adb shell am start -W -n com.facebook.katana/.com.face
book.account.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity -S -a android.intent.action.MAIN
 -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f 0x10200000
```

but it is giving me an error,

```
Error: Activity class {com.facebook.katana/com.facebook.katana.com.facebook.acco
unt.login.activity.SimpleLoginActivity} does not exist.
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it might be because of the appActivity, but how can i get the main activity?

Answer (score 0):

First cross check your main activity using below link.

http://www.automationtestinghub.com/apppackage-and-appactivity-name/

If still you are getting same error then  `android:exported="true"` should be in AndroidManifest.xml for main activity/specified activity.

Comment: I had already tried the first method as mentioned in my question. I tried the second method as well, but the app Apk info doesnt have an activities section now.

Answer (score -1):

The exception is pretty clear: for *security reason* activity start is blocked.

You need to set `android:exported="true"` in AndroidManifest.xml file where `SimpleLoginActivity` is declared. I guess you don't have access to Facebook App source code to fix that.

Appium is pretty flexible tool, but if AUT has security restrictions Appium cannot do anything with it.

Comment: Hi, I dont know where this Manifest file is. I never had to use it because I am a tester. I use appium just to get the elements to automate. What should I do to get past the exception?

Comment: You need source code of the app to change it and build new apk. Currently you can't test it